# How to trigger the alarm?

Tags: pine-script

Hello I was searching some indicators and found what I needed.
This indicator has an alarm that triggers only when the MA rises, but there is no alarm that trigger when the MA falls, so I added it myself.
But sadly it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// === Moving Average//

ma_series = variant(ma_type,ma_src,ma_len)
direction = 0
direction := rising(ma_series,reaction) ? 1 : falling(ma_series,reaction) ? -1 : nz(direction[1])
up= change(direction,1)
down= change(direction,-1)
pcol = direction>0 ? lime : direction<0 ? red : na
plot(ma_series, color=pcol,style=line,join=true,linewidth=3,transp=10,title=MA PLOT)


/////// Alerts ///////

alertcondition(up,title=Change Direction Rising,message=Change Direction Rising)
alertcondition(down,title=Change Direction Falling,message=Change Direction Falling)**
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkp1U.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a negative number for the length argument in `change()`.
Try modifying up/dn :

```
up = direction == 1 and nz(direction[1], 0) != 1
down = direction == -1 and nz(direction[1], 0) != -1
```